# Program "make" not found in PATH ,Eclipse ESP8266

Tags: eclipse, path, esp8266

I spent many hours trying to configure Eclipse for compiling basics example projects for ESP8266.
I did some step back .
Despite i followed the instructions(or at least i think)at https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp8266-rtos-sdk/en/latest/get-started/index.html#setup-path-to-esp8266-rtos-sdk now i'm not even able to compile hello_world without "Error: Program "make" not found in PATH",I should force a different path where make.exe is, but I don't understand why I was told to use that path .Anyway  if in Project ->Properties->C/C++ Buid->Environment I add the path where make.exe is (C:\msys32\usr\bin) i have a new error:
Makefile:8: DF_PATH/requirements.txt;C:\msys32\home\Administrator\esp\ESP8266_RTOS_SDK/make/project.mk: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target 'DF_PATH/requirements.txt;C:\msys32\home\Administrator\esp\ESP8266_RTOS_SDK/make/project.mk'.  Stop.

Notice that if i flag the option Generate Makefiles Automatically the problem disappear,so why i was told to uncheck it in tutorials?
Is there any step i missed outside Eclipse?":
You also need to use the command line to configure your
ESP8266_RTOS_SDK project (via make menuconfig ), this is not currently supported inside Eclipse"
if I run make menuconfig from the directory where the project is i still have
Administrator@Lella-HP MINGW32 /c/msys32/home/Administrator/esp/ESP8266_RTOS_SDK/examples/get-started/hello_world

## make menuconfig

Makefile:8: DF_PATH/requirements.txt/make/project.mk: No such file or directory
make: ***  no rule to make target
"DF_PATH/requirements.txt/make/project.mk".  Arrested.

NB i have W7 64bit and i'm using msys32.

Thanks for your time,

Diego

Comment: set the IDF_PATH environment variable. https://my-esp-idf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/get-started/index.html#setup-path-to-esp-idf the examples and IDF have makefiles so Eclipse should not generate them

Comment: Thanks,
 i changed many times IDF_PATH
in  Control Panel->User Variables for Admin. IDF_PATH:
python -m pip install --user -r $IDF_PATH/requirements.txt
in C.Pan->System Variables->IDF_PATH is C:\msys32\usr\bin;C:\msys32\home\Administrator\esp\ESP8266_RTOS_SDK
ESP8266_RTOS_SDK is the directory of"requirements.txt"and folder"make" ->"project.mk"
Running from MinGW32 terminal “make” or “make menuconfig” gives
Makefile:8: DF_PATH/requirements.txt/make/project.mk: No such file or directory
make: ***  No rule to make target "DF_PATH/requirements.txt/mak                      e/project.mk".

Comment: I hope I  do a correct use of comments

furthermore,i tried changing the Makefile content in project directory,
commenting the original line and adding a line with an absolute path instead of IDF_PATH:
#include $(IDF_PATH)/make/project.mk
include c:\msys32\home\Administrator\esp\ESP8266_RTOS_SDK/make/project.mk

Comment: (I hope I'm using comments correctly )
Then i tried changing the Makefile content in project directory,
commenting the original line and adding a line with an absolute path instead of IDF_PATH:
#include $(IDF_PATH)/make/project.mk
include c:\msys32\home\Administrator\esp\ESP8266_RTOS_SDK/make/project.mk

Issuing "make" in MinGW terminal now gives : IDF_PATH variable is not set                                        to a valid directory .Maybe is it a matter of slash-backslash ..colons-semicolons?Thanks

Comment: with the intention of helping you to help me:
the command "env" in MinGW terminal returns
IDF_PATH=python -m pip install --user -r $IDF_PATH/requirements.txt
and once more i ask myself why a text file is used in a path,but i see that it contains some python stuff whose meaning I do not know
click>=5.0
pyserial>=3.0
future>=0.15.2
cryptography>=2.1.4
pyparsing>=2.0.3,<2.4.0
pyelftools>=0.22

Comment: you must set it right to C:\msys32\home\Administrator\esp\ESP8266_RTOS_SDK https://my-esp-idf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/get-started/add-idf_path-to-profile.html#add-idf-path-to-profile-windows

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Juray for the help, 
changing the idf path to the installation folder ,C:\msys32\home\Administrator\esp\ESP8266_RTOS_SDK did not solve,but moved and showed something different:
Issuing      make menuconfig
showed a verbose response, different from any other I got before,I failed to copy it,sorry,in few words it said that whas something wrong in python dependencies and i had to run something called "pacman" or in alternative i was told to use :
C:/msys32/mingw32/bin/python.exe -m pip install --user -r C:/msys32/home/Administrator/esp/ESP8266_RTOS_SDK/requirements.txt
After that running make menuconfig worked in the expected way,as showed in
https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp8266-rtos-sdk/en/latest/get-started/index.html#get-esp8266-rtos-sdk
A step ahead,maybe something else is missing to compile, but the problems of path seems going in the right direction.